# Finding column in a table and pull the the values if exist else refer other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im trying to check for a column[EMPID] in a table [EMPLOYEE] if exist i have to consider the values from that column, if not it have to refer to another TAble[Details] and column[EMPID]. Please somebody can answer this.

```
select distinct EMPLYEENAME,(
select case 
   when exists (select 1 from sys.columns where Name = 'EMPID' and 
   object_id=object_id('EMPLOYEE'))
   then 1
   else 0 
end EMPID) EMPID from EMPLOYEE
)k
```

so here in the place of '1' and '0' i have to pull values from DETAILS table and EMPLOYEE table

Comment: Please add which SQL database you using in your tags?

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Add a tag for the database you are using.  The question might make sense to you  Remember you are communicating to strangers.

Comment: I would consider this bad database design.  Normally, you shouldn't be worrying about if a column _exists_, but rather about the data in a particular column.

Comment: Sample table data will be required in your question to figure out a solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to do something like this. Check for the column first before executing the query, that way you will not get missing column errors:

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.columns where Name = 'EMPID' and object_id=object_id('EMPLOYEE'))
    select distinct EMPLYEENAME, EMPID from EMPLOYEE
ELSE
    select distinct EMPLYEENAME, 0 AS EMPID from EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check the column name if it has on the table, if not, this will select from another table

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'EMPID' AND object_id=object_id('EMPLOYEE'))
    SELECT DISTINCT employeename,
           empid
      FROM employee
ELSE
    SELECT columns -- list your column names here
      FROM details
```